# AND Formula not working as expected - EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am facing a strange issue there :

```
=AND(MONTH(VLOOKUP(B25,'Liste-Stagiaire'!$1:$1048576,8,FALSE)) & YEAR(VLOOKUP(B25,'Liste-Stagiaire'!$1:$1048576,8,FALSE))<= MONTH(Octobre!$A$2) & YEAR(Octobre!$A$2))
```

**Where :**

```
=MOIS(RECHERCHEV(B25;'Liste-Stagiaire'!$1:$1048576;8;FAUX)) & ANNEE(RECHERCHEV(B25;'Liste-Stagiaire'!$1:$1048576;8;FAUX))
```

Output : **72019**

```
=MONTH(VLOOKUP(B25,'Liste-Stagiaire'!$1:$1048576,8,FALSE)) & YEAR(VLOOKUP(B25,'Liste-Stagiaire'!$1:$1048576,8,FALSE))
```

Output : **102019**

So that give the formula :

`=AND(72019 <= 102019 )`

The **excepted** output would be `TRUE` But **the output I got is** `FALSE`

What am I missing here ?

Comment: `&` turns the numbers into text and text will determine greater than or less than character by character starting on the left `7>1`

Comment: wrap each part in `VALUE`

Comment: Could you please post the formulas in English? You can translate them using https://stackoverflow.com/a/57804890/9199828

Comment: I get `TRUE` with `=AND(72019 <= 102019 )`  but `FALSE` with `=AND("72019" <= "102019" )` which is why you need `=AND(VALUE("72019") <= VALUE("102019") )`

Comment: You can highlight parts of your formula and use F9, or use `Formulas/Evaluate formula`

Comment: @ScottCraner doesn't `value(month(a2)&year(a2))` product crazy dates due to the order of the date?  You can do this a different way to normalize to months, which will be possibly easier... let me put that in an answer

Comment: No it would create a number:  `Value(Month("1/1/2019")&Year("1/1/2019"))` would return `VALUE("12019")` which then returns `12019` as a anumber.  @Cyril

Comment: Why are you concatenating the month with the year?  why not just work with the raw date?  if you are going to make a date comparisson through concatenation the order would normally be YY MM DD HH MM SS.  Start from the largest unit and work towards smallest

Comment: @ScottCraner heard; i didn't chagne the formatting of my test with that... 112018 > 72019, so still a separate issue, which I believe normalizing months would help (listed in my answer... but hard to test without remaking all of the sheets).

Comment: @Cyril you are correct, I added a better method that uses the dates and not the numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&` turns the numbers into text and text will determine greater than or less than character by character starting on the left `7>1`

Use VALUE to turn the text into numbers:

```
=AND(VALUE(MONTH(VLOOKUP(B25,'Liste-Stagiaire'!$1:$1048576,8,FALSE)) & YEAR(VLOOKUP(B25,'Liste-Stagiaire'!$1:$1048576,8,FALSE)))<= VALUE(MONTH(Octobre!$A$2) & YEAR(Octobre!$A$2)))
```

But as [@ForwardEd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57856672/and-formula-not-working-as-expected-excel/57856936#comment102140043_57856672) And [@Cyryl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57856672/and-formula-not-working-as-expected-excel/57856936#comment102140285_57856960) stated, using dates may be better and avoid the conversion to and from strings, or the fact that `112018>072019`

```
=AND(DATE(YEAR(VLOOKUP(B25,'Liste-Stagiaire'!$1:$1048576,8,FALSE)),MONTH(VLOOKUP(B25,'Liste-Stagiaire'!$1:$1048576,8,FALSE)),1)<=DATE(YEAR(Octobre!$A$2),MONTH(Octobre!$A$2),1)
```

Comment: I missed your edit... looks like you beat my main-post comment to the chase.

Comment: I used the **Date** Way which seems better, Thanks all for your suggestion !

Comment: Please review typo in the second formula. Perhaps two brackets `))` are required at the end of the formula.

Answer (score 1):

You are making one comparison, so you can compare similar to:

```
=(Year(VLookUp(B25;'Liste-Stagiaire'!$1:$1048576;8;FAUX))*12)+Value(Month(Search(B25,'Liste-Stagiaire'!$1:$1048576,8,FALSE))<(Year(Octobre!A2)*12+Month(Octobre!A2))
```

Essentially, instead of making a string or comparison with 72019, you would be looking at total number of months:

```
2019*12 + 7  <  2019*12 + 10
```

Note that doing it this way will normalize all months.

---

Edit:

Will give an example of swapping to index/match to support this:

```
=(Year(Index(Sheet2!$H$1:$H$200,Match(B25,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$200,0))*12+Month(Index(Sheet2!$H$1:$H$200,Match(B25,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$200,0)))<=(Year(Octobre!A2)*12+Month(Octobre!A2))
```

I also shortened the lookup/index ranges, which will be a HUGE saver of performance (you had all sheets used, 1:1048576 which eats up a LOT).  Found the 8th column ("H") and output from that using `index`.

Comment: Your idea is nice but i think that it will impact excel performances, since I got a lot of formula which are using a lot of CPU .. 

Kindest regards

Comment: @Dorian Understandable.  I had just made a comment to Scott on the main post about the comparison of 112018 (Nov 2018) > 72019 (Jul 2019), which might throw flags to your whole approach.  If you are having issues with performance, you may want to change your vlookup to `index`/`match` and use a smaller range (you're using the entire set of rows in your example).