# Is there a way to remove last characters from date column in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For a function within QGIS I need to transform my datetime column into a datetime column without miliseconds.

datetime

2019-07-05T23:55:02.0000

2019-07-05T23:55:05.0000

2019-07-05T23:55:11.0000

datetime_new

2019-07-05T23:55:02

2019-07-05T23:55:05

2019-07-05T23:55:11

Could you guys help me with this issue?

I tried to use the =LEFT(column, LEN(column)-5) but it gives me an error

EDIT: Appears to be  a language issue, I was not able to use the LEFT or MID calculation while my excel version is DUTCH.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Is column referring to a single cell?

Comment: F.E. if "2019-07-05T23:55:02.0000" is on cell A2 and you place `=LEFT(A2, LEN(A2)-5)` on some other cell, you will get your result. Just Drag... Have you define column on the Name Manager?

Comment: When I try this last option I reveive the value #NAME? in the cell

Comment: Can't you just format the cells with a custom format of `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss` and save it as a csv?

Comment: #NAME? is because the function your are trying to use is incorrect (typo maybe). In a new workbook try copying and pasting `=LEFT(A2, LEN(A2)-5)` into cell A1 then put your value `2019-07-05T23:55:02.0000` into A2 and see what happens.

Comment: The data is already produced unfortunately, and there are more than 100.000 lines with datetime so I have no other choice

Comment: [This might come in handy for you in the future](https://nl.excel-translator.de/zoekresultaat/?mssearch=left) for the rest, @Plato77 answer should work perfectly.

Comment: So `=LINKS(A2, 19)`

Comment: @NielsJanssens but you're in Excel, so just change the number-format?

Comment: *Appears to be a language issue* @NielsJanssens Please read **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57804890/9199828)** about how to translate the functions names to your language (dutch in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the data is always the same length (with a value in cell D6), you could use  =LEFT(D6,19)