# How to sum 2 cells with value like "9 (1)" and "10 (2)"?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 cells with those values:

```
9 (1) 
10 (2)
```

and I want to sum them like :

```
19 (3)
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: So what have you tried so far? If you can share what you have done so far and where you got stuck then we can better address your need. I would suggest you to use helper columns to extract the first and second number first, and then combine them back into the desired structure if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably multiple ways but you could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A1:A2,SEARCH("(",A1:A2)-1)*1)&" ("&SUMPRODUCT(MID(A1:A2,SEARCH("(",A1:A2)+1,LEN(A1:A2)-SEARCH("(",A1:A2)-1)*1)&")"
```

Comment: Thanks @jvdV! however I have an error when i try to use your formula (There's a problem with this formula)

Comment: @Stephane, what language Excel you using? And maybe more importantly, what type of parameter delimiters? Semicolon or comma?

Comment: I don't know, how to see this ?

Comment: @Stephane to translate the functions to your language in Excel, you first need to know if you work in english, french, spanish or other language. Second, to translate formulas, you can read this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57804890/9199828  Also, depending on your Excel version, arguments in functions can be separated with "," or with ";". You also need to know that.