# Excel french issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Excel sheet with value and another column value that depend of theme
If value >48  the value will be 8  if <=40  value will be 0  if value inferior a 48 and supperieru a 40 value will be column -40   I tried this but didn't work

```
=SI(AH15>48,8,SI(ET(AH15>40,AH15<48,AH15-40))
```

Or english:

```
=IF(AH15>48,8,IF(AND(AH15>40,AH15<48,AH15-40))
```

Comment: Please, post the formulas in english. [Read here how to translate them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57804890/9199828)

Comment: Try this one: `=SI(AH15>48,8,SI(ET(AH15>40,AH15<48),AH15-40,0))`... Next time in English, please...

Comment: What if the value it's exactly 48?

Comment: I am just following the description. user2128925 did not mention what it is expected on AH=48

Comment: Anyhow... `=SI(AH15>48,8,SI(ET(AH15>40,AH15<=48),AH15-40,0))`

Answer (score 2):

You are throwing in an `AND` function to check multiple conditions in a wrong manner:

All these conditions `ET(AH15>40,AH15<48,AH15-40)` can never be true since the last parameter is a calculation. Either way, what you tried to do is maybe:

```
=SI(AH15<=40,0,SI(AH15>48,8,AH15-40))
```

Which translates to:

```
=IF(AH15<=40,0,IF(AH15>48,8,AH15-40))
```

Comment: I got an error <when I try this  =SI(AH15<=40,0,SI(AH15>48,8,AH15-40))

Comment: @user2128925, you maybe are using semicolon instead of comma as the seperators: `=SI(AH15<=40;0;SI(AH15>48;8;AH15-40))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
=IF(AH15>48,8,IF(AND(AH15>40,AH15<=48),AH15-40,0))
```

Hope it helps